# AngularJS - directive scope model doesn't update without debugger

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

For create/edit a website content I have a form with some tabs (buttons making the idea of tabs system because the user may want to add another "tab", etc, etc) and I use a directive to show the selected tab:

```
<form name="form" novalidate>
    <div class="tabsContainer">
        <!--some button making the idea of tabs system-->
    </div>

    <div class="contentDataContainer">
        <content-form ng-model="VM.CurrentContent" page-features="VM.PageFeatures"></content-form>
    </div>
</form>
```

When the user want to edit the content I request content data to the web service:

```
loadData = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    ContentsService.GetContentToCreateEdit({ id: vm.IdContent })
        .then(function(response)
        {
            try {
                if (vm.IdContent <= 0 || (response.ResultOperation === ResultEnum.Success && exists(response.ResultObject.Contents)))
                {
                    vm.Model = ContentVM.GetModelToShow(response.ResultObject.Contents);
                    vm.CurrentContent = vm.Model[0];
                }
                else 
                {
                    //some like with error messages
                }
            }
            catch (err) { }

        deferred.resolve();              
    }, function () {
        deferred.resolve();
    });

    LoadingService.Load(deferred.promise, 'first');
};
```

And directive's model must updates.

**Directive controller:**

```
vm.Model = { Id: 0 };

function init()
{            
    vm.Model = exists($scope.model) ? $scope.model : getDefaultContentInfo(); 

    if(isStringEmpty(vm.Model.Price)) vm.Model.Price = "";
    vm.Model.PriceText = vm.Model.Price;
    vm.Model.IsIntervalDate = !isStringEmpty(vm.Model.EndDate) && vm.Model.EndDate != vm.Model.StartDate;
};

init();

$scope.$watch($scope.model, function () {
    init();
}, true);
```

If I put a `debugger` inside the `init()` function the directive updates perfectly with the `$scope.model` but if I haven't it doesn't...

Someone can explain what is happenning here and how can I solve this?

I already tried to use `$scope.$apply()` but I got a digest error and I already tried to use a `$timeout()` but directive's model doesn't updates nither.

```
$timeout(function () {
    init();

    $scope.$watch($scope.model, function () {
        init();
    }, true);
},500);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After implementing a form validation I needed to show model errors and the problem appears again. And finaly after many headaches and found the problem.

In my `$scope.$watch`

```
$scope.$watch($scope.model, function () {
    init();
}, true);
```

The *watchExpression* must be idempotence and so I change the code to this

```
$scope.$watch('model', function () {
    init();
}, true);
```

And now works!!!

For more documentation [click here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Answer (score 0):

Your `vm.Model` is probably not set when you enter the init. With the debugger, you are waiting enough time for the variable to get set.
If the `getDefaultContentInfo()` returns a promise, what you need to do is set the variable to your data in the `then` function returned from the promise.

Comment: In the `getDefaultContentInfo()` I just return an object like `return { Id: 0 };`  . The only promise I have is in the controller view where directive is called, the `loadData()` showed in my question. It's possible that be the problem? The `$q.defer()` in `loadData()`? The `$scope.$watch()` in the directive shouldn't be handling with that change?

Comment: Then that is the problem. you do not want your html to load(with the directive) until you load the data. i would call `loadData()` in the init function and set a variable when its completed. Then i would check that variable `ng-if="initDone"` before loading the page

Comment: But `$scope.$watch()` shouldn't be handling with this?